# How does $g\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$ affect the ratio $\lambda_i(gL)/\lambda_i(L)$ of a lattice $L$

Tags: lie-groups, estimation, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $L\le \mathbb R^n$ be a lattice and $g\in GL(n,\mathbb R)$. Suppose $g$ is fixed but $L$ is allowed to vary.

Let $\lambda_i(L)$ be the $i$-th minimum of the lattice $L$ for $1\le i \le n$. I wonder if there are lower and upper bounds of $\lambda_i(gL)/\lambda_i(L)$ that are independent of the choice of $L$ and $1\le i \le n$ (but could depend on $g$ and $n$).

I am inclined to believe that this is false and trying to come up with a lattice and $g$ such that the ratio above could be very small. There is an upper bound when $i=1$ and lower bound when $i=n$. See the link below.

What I asked is different from the following thread, where we compared different minima:

[How does the action of $GL(n,\mathbb R)$ affect the $k$-th minimum of a lattice?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3857114/how-does-the-action-of-gln-mathbb-r-affect-the-k-th-minimum-of-a-lattice)

Comment: Are you working on any particular book?

Comment: @WillJagy No. This is just inspired from the papers I read. I doubt this particular question can be answered in any textbook. Please let me know if it is.

Comment: I expect Lekkerkerker and Gruber would help. https://books.google.com/books?id=eYeWNW8mzXMC&source=gbs_similarbooks    As you like the sequence of minima, also Cassels, which I do have. For that matter, Olds et. al. is a good idea to start https://books.google.com/books?id=Bycut_duHr8C&source=gbs_similarbooks  I don't have that either

Comment: @WillJagy thanks. I have tried to search in some books on geometry of numbers, but fail to find anything that could possibly give answer to my question. Do you know any particular pages of particular books I can look at?

Comment: Also do you believe the bound on $\lambda_i(gL)/\lambda_i(L)$ is independent of $L$?